# Is it normal for Blender to use so much memory when I have a graphics card?

Tags: rendering, gpu, memory-management

[image]
I feel like my pc should be using my graphics card more when I'm editing and rendering but it will only use up to 7% of it when it renders. Is there a way to make my pc use more?

Comment: Is blender configured to be using your gpu?

Comment: I already went to Settings > Display > Graphics Settings and set graphics preference for Blender to high performance if that's what you're asking.

Comment: No, you have to actually set blender to use your gpu, if are using cycles. I’m not sure about eevee

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I had already set it up to use my gpu and it was just not in the Rendering view. However, Blender was still using so much memory for some reason. Normally I restart my pc when it starts using so much to refresh it. There might be some other way to stop that entirely.

Comment: Blender will never use only your GPU, there are many tasks that remain for the CPU, system RAM and local storage to perform. If you have set Blender's [Cycles Rendering Device setting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html), and set your render engine to use your GPU, then it should use the GPU **when it can**. That's about it.